# How to get the JWT's secretOrKey from remote in NestJS?

Tags: node.js, json, jwt, nestjs, consul

Here is my code to verify incoming request using JWT in NestJS:

```
import { ExtractJwt, Strategy } from 'passport-jwt';
import { PassportStrategy } from '@nestjs/passport';
import { Injectable } from '@nestjs/common';

@Injectable()
export class JwtStrategy extends PassportStrategy(Strategy) {
  constructor() {
    super({
      jwtFromRequest: ExtractJwt.fromAuthHeaderAsBearerToken(),
      ignoreExpiration: false,
      secretOrKey: 'test',
    });
  }

  async validate(payload: any) {
    return {
      userId: payload.sub,
      username: payload.username,
    };
  }
}
```

It works well when I set the secretOrKey to 'test' (define the secretOrKey locally).
For security reason, I want to read the secretOrKey from the key/value in Consul (or Redis):

```
import { ExtractJwt, Strategy } from 'passport-jwt';
import { PassportStrategy } from '@nestjs/passport';
import { Injectable } from '@nestjs/common';
import { listSecret } from './constants';

@Injectable()
export class JwtStrategy extends PassportStrategy(Strategy) {
  constructor(private readonly Secret: listSecret) {
    super({
      jwtFromRequest: ExtractJwt.fromAuthHeaderAsBearerToken(),
      ignoreExpiration: false,
      secretOrKey: Secret.listSec(),
    });
  }

  async validate(payload: any) {
    return {
      userId: payload.sub,
      username: payload.username,
    };
  }
}
```

Here is the listSecret:

```
import { Consul } from '../Consul';
import { Inject, Injectable } from '@nestjs/common';
@Injectable()
export class listSecret {
  constructor(
    private consul: Consul,
  ) {}
  async listSec() {
    const JWT_KEY = await this.consul.ConsulUse(
      'https://192.168.1.1:8501/v1/kv/jwt',
    );
    return JWT_KEY;
  }
}
```

When I run the app to send a request with the JWT, I get the :

```
{
    "statusCode": 401,
    "message": "Unauthorized"
}
```

It seems that the secretOrKey could not get the right value (I guess it could have a 'Promise { < pending > }' in return). So, I think it would use 'async/await' in the
constructor (jwt.strategy.ts), but I can not find a way to do that (the Consul is working well).

Thanks

Comment: Hi @Erika, how did you solve? Thanks

Answer (score 1):

I am late to the party, so it might not be useful for OP anymore. But I am hoping that it will help others in the future.

I ran into the same issue and the good people over at NestJS helped me out with it.

In my case, my aim was to have a useful setup which is useful for local development as well as production environment. So my local dev reads the configuration information from the `.env` file, whereas the production environment reads from **GCP Secrets Manager**.

My application needs the following configuration information:

```
DATABASE_HOST=mongodb://localhost/order
JWT_SECRET=testkey
JWT_EXPIRES_IN=15d
```

I quickly wrote a basic configuration service:

**settings.service.ts**:

```js
import { Injectable } from '@nestjs/common';

@Injectable()
export abstract class SettingsService {
  abstract get(key: string): Promise<string>;
}
```

**env-settings.service.ts**:

```js
import { Injectable } from '@nestjs/common';
import { SettingsService } from './settings.service';

@Injectable()
export class EnvironmentSettingsService implements SettingsService {
  async get(key: string) {
    return process.env[key];
  }
}
```

and,

**gcp-secrets.service.ts**:

```js
import { Injectable } from '@nestjs/common';
import { SettingsService } from './settings.service';
import { SecretManagerServiceClient } from '@google-cloud/secret-manager';

// environment value provided dynamically by Google Cloud Run at runtime
const GCP_PROJECT_ID = process.env.PROJECT_ID;

@Injectable()
export class GcpSecretsSettingsService implements SettingsService {
  async get(key: string) {
    const secretClient = new SecretManagerServiceClient();

    const [version] = await secretClient.accessSecretVersion({
      name: `projects/${GCP_PROJECT_ID}/secrets/${key}/versions/latest`,
    });

    console.log(`secret [${key}]`, version.payload.data.toString());
    return version.payload.data.toString();
  }
}
```

Here, I hit my first challenge: How to register MongooseModule and JWTModule using an async function?
You see, most of the examples out there simply show the use of `process.env.JWT_SECRET` and `process.env.MONGO_HOST`.

This is the right way to do it:

First, put the settings classes in a separate module. So move the files into a separate folder (or howsoever you wish to manage modules in your application). I put them in `src/modules/settings`.

Create the module declaration:

**src/modules/settings/settings.module.ts**

```js
@Module({
  providers: [
    {
      provide: SettingsService,
      inject: [EnvironmentSettingsService, GcpSecretsSettingsService],
      useFactory: (envService, gcpService) => {
        return process.env.NODE_ENV === 'production' ? gcpService : envService;
      },
    },
    EnvironmentSettingsService,
    GcpSecretsSettingsService,
  ],
  exports: [SettingsService],
})
export class SettingsModule {}
```

Note how the appropriate class is provided based on the environment.

**app.module.ts**

```js
@Module({
  imports: [
    SettingsModule,
    ...
    ...
    MongooseModule.forRootAsync({
      imports: [SettingsModule, MongooseModule],
      useFactory: async (settingsService: SettingsService) => ({
        uri: await settingsService.get('DATABASE_HOST'),
        useNewUrlParser: true,
        useUnifiedTopology: true,
        connectionFactory: (connection) => {
          // any mongoose plugins that need to be registered
          return connection;
        },
      }),
      inject: [SettingsService],
    }),
    JwtModule.registerAsync({
      imports: [SettingsModule, JwtModule],
      useFactory: async (settingsService: SettingsService) => ({
        secret: await settingsService.get('JWT_SECRET'),
        signOptions: { expiresIn: await settingsService.get('JWT_EXPIRES_IN') },
      }),
      inject: [SettingsService],
    }),
  ...
  ...
  ],
  ...
  ...
})
export class AppModule {}
```

For the JwtStrategy class, which needs access to the JWT_SECRET for initialization, the trick is to inject the value, rather than access it directly using an `async` function.

So, in **app.module.ts**, under `providers`, provide the appropriate value:

```js
@Module({
  imports: [...],
  providers: [
    ...
    ...
    {
      provide: 'JWT_SECRET',
      inject: [SettingsService],
      useFactory: async (settingsService: SettingsService) =>
        settingsService.get('JWT_SECRET'),
    },
    ...
    ...
  ],
  ...
  ...
})
```

**jwt-strategy.service.ts**

```js
@Injectable()
export class JwtStrategy extends PassportStrategy(Strategy) {
  constructor(
    @Inject('JWT_SECRET') jwtSecret,
  ) {
    super({
      jwtFromRequest: ExtractJwt.fromAuthHeaderAsBearerToken(),
      ignoreExpiration: false,
      secretOrKey: jwtSecret,
    });
  }
  ...
  ...
}
```

And that should do the trick.